# What is the purpose of score for a user in elastic search query result?

Tags: elasticsearch

The main difference between must and filter query is the _score calculation.
Can anyone tell me what is the purpose of the score shown in the query result?
How can we use the score?

Answer (score 1):

The score gives you the relevance of a given document to the executed query. The higher the score, the more relevant is the document. For example, consider the following documents:

```
# Doc 1
{
  "title": "What is the purpose of score for a user in elastic search query result?"
}

# Doc 2
{
  "title": "What is the purpose of score in life?"
}
```

Then, if you query for a title that includes the words `purpose score elastic` (something you would do, for example, in the stackoverflow search bar), the first document will get a higher score and will appear on top of the list of results.

On the other hand, filters tell you whether a document matches or not the query. It is either a yes or no, therefore, it is not necessary to calculate the score.

For further details, have a read at the always very good [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-filter-context.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know any use of the score? I mean any practical example where the relevance of the score matter.

Comment: I updated the original answer. However, I would recommend you to have a look at the basics of search engines, in general, and of Elasticsearch in particular.